# Unity web open custom html after build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a custom html file for my Unity web project. Though after building my project, it opens the default pre-made one. Is there a way to make Unity open my own html file instead of the default one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [Web Player Templates manual page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingWebPlayertemplates.html).

In your `Assets` folder, create a folder named `WebPlayerTemplates`, and put your template in there. You'll need an HTML file. To help make this slightly easier, Unity will look in that HTML for certain tokens that it can replace with data from the project.

For example, one such tag is `%UNITY_WEB_PATH%`, which will be replaced with the path to your built project file.

Some tags include:

> UNITY_WEB_NAME Name of the webplayer.
>
> UNITY_WIDTH UNITY_HEIGHT Onscreen width and height of the player in
>   pixels.
>
> UNITY_WEB_PATH Local path to the webplayer file.
>
> UNITY_UNITYOBJECT_URL In the usual case where the page will download
>   UnityObject2.js from the Unity’s website (ie, the Offline Deployment
>   option is disabled), this tag will provide the download URL.
>
> UNITY_UNITYOBJECT_DEPENDENCIES The UnityObject2.js have dependencies
>   and this tag will be replaced with the needed dependencies for it to
>   work properly.

In every deployment I've seen, the WebPlayer plugin is is launched via JavaScript, by instantiating a `UnityObject2` and calling its `initPlugin` method:

```
var u = new UnityObject2();
u.initPlugin(jQuery("#unityPlayer")[0], "Example.unity3d");
```

The above assumes that you have a `div` with id `#unityPlayer`, and that `Example.unity3d` is a valid path to your Unity build file.

In practice, though, I recommend working from Unity's generated HTML files; they include some failsafes for cases where the WebPlayer plugin isn't installed or fails to load. The manual page linked above also has HTML source examples which include some of those special tags.

`UnityObject2` does have some advanced features, which are [also documented in the manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WorkingwithUnityObject.html). If your game needs to communicate with the outer web page, [that is also possible](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html).

Comment: Brilliant! How could I have missed that page... This worked perfectly :D